# How to pass a variable description to Stripe Checkout Express backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm building a Stripe Custom Checkout Integration that allows users to register and pay for an event. The registration options are very simple and consist of just 4 categories - all at the same price.

I've been successful in passing the category titles to the description parameter in the Stripe Checkout popup, but am having trouble passing the same description parameter to the Stripe API.

After a successful test charge, Stripe returns the object with 'description: null'.

Adding a string to the description parameter correctly returns the string, however I'd like it to return the category title set in my form.

INDEX.HTML

```
   <script>      

        var checkoutHandler = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: "pk_test_stripeTestKey",
            locale: "auto",
        });

       // var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
        // button.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {

        function checkout(ev) {
        var description = $('#categoryDesc').val();
        checkoutHandler.open({
        image: "/cj-stripe-icon.jpg",
        name: 'The EVENT 2019',
        description: description, //$("#categoryDesc").val() + " - " + "$130",
        amount: 13000,
        token: handleToken
    });
};
// });

            function handleToken(token) {
                fetch("/charge", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                    body: JSON.stringify(token)
                })
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok)
                        throw response;
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(output => {
                    console.log("Purchase succeeded:", output);
                    submitToAPI(event);
                    document.getElementById("shop").innerHTML = "<h2>Thank you for registering!</h2><h3>You should receive an email confirmation shortly.</h3>";
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("Purchase failed:", err);
                })
            }               

            </script>
```

APP.JS

```
onst express = require("express");
const stripe = require("stripe")(keySecret);
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public")); // serves content from the public directory

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/charge", (req, res) => {
  let amount = 13000;

  stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email,
    card: req.body.id
  })
  .then(customer =>
    stripe.charges.create({
      amount,
      currency: "usd",
      description: req.body.description,
      customer: customer.id
    }))
    .then(charge => res.send(charge))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error:", err);
      res.status(500).send({error: "Purchase Failed"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd build a new Javascript object when you get the Token response in your front-end.  It should contain two attributes: (a) your Token ID and (b) some ENUM/Description that maps to a set price/service on your backend.

eg.

```
var payload = {
  tokenId: token.id,
  productId: <<some product id>>
}
```

Then on your backend, you should retrieve this information.

eg.

```
var PRODUCTS = {
  // productId: {description: 'Cat Mittens', price: 2000, ...}
  product1: {description: 'Product #1', price: 1000},
  product2: {description: 'Product #2', price: 2000}
}

if (!(req.body.productId in PRODUCTS)) {
  // Couldn't find the product id in the product list-- raise an error!
}

var product = PRODUCTS[req.body.productId];
```

That way you can get the description to map between your front-end and back-end.  If you don't do something like this, someone malicious might change the product they're purchasing or the description of the product they're purchasing or maybe even the value of the product they're purchasing.  So best practice here is to share some sort of enum.

The other cool thing this lets you do is validate the token on your backend.  You can see more details about the token when you attempt to retrieve it with your Secret API Key that you can't see when you simply create it with the Publishable API Key.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks korben. As this is a learning project for me, I'll need to figure out how to implement a solution such as yours.

Comment: I am also wondering if Stripe is blocking the 'description' parameter sent to Stripe, as I can have a variable 'amount' implemented similarly to what I've tried above. 

I was also intending to put the 'amount' in environment variables as suggested by Stripe docs.